# ons-alert-dialogのボタン色を変えたい

Tags: css

ons-alert-dialogで「はい」「いいえ」を表示させ
「はい」は青色で、「いいえ」は赤色で表示させるにはどのようにしたらよいのでしょうか？
onsen-css-components.cssで色は変更できるのはわかったのですが
それぞれの色を指定する場合がわかりません

Answer (score 1):

`.alert-dialog-button`の`color: rgba(red,green,blue,alpha);`がソレにあたりますが、
ボタン全てに対し反映されているので、変更してしまうと全てのボタンが変わってしまいます。
ですので`nth-child`でボタン1番目、ボタン2番目みたいに選択して
それぞれに自分のスタイルを書くしかないんじゃないですかね？
こんな感じで……

```
.alert-dialog-button:nth-child(1){
  color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
}
.alert-dialog-button:nth-child(2){
  color: rgba(0,0,255,1);
}
```

ただ、1つ注意なのが、`confirm`でも`alert`でも同じクラスが使われます。
なので、`alert`の場合は`nth-child(1)`のクラスが当てられます。
だんだん考えていて複雑になってきたので、こんなもんで……あとは工夫ですかね？

Comment: ありがとうございました。無事解決しました